# Split Date Time string (not in usual format) and pull out month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe that has a date time string but is not in traditional date time format. I would like to separate out the date from the time into two separate columns. And then eventually also separate out the month.

This is what the date/time string looks like: `2019-03-20T16:55:52.981-06:00`

```
>>> df.head()
Date                             Score
2019-03-20T16:55:52.981-06:00    10
2019-03-07T06:16:52.174-07:00    9
2019-06-17T04:32:09.749-06:003   1
```

I tried this but got a type error:

```
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
```

Comment: Is your `Date` column a string or a datetime object?

Comment: It works for me. Could you post the error please?

Comment: Um, that *is* the traditional date time format.  It is [the ISO 8601 Extended Date and Time Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), also covered by [RFC 3339 - Date and Time on the Internet: Timestamps](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339).

Comment: That is, except for that extra `3` in the last row.  Is that a typo? or does your string actually contain `-06:003`?  If so, what does it *mean*?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date

Comment: Apologies...That last row was a typo with the extra 3. I hadn't seen the string in that format before, but it looks like the answer below resolved it. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done just using `pandas` itself. You can first convert the `Date` column to `datetime` by passing `utc = True`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], utc = True)
```

And then just extract the month using `dt.month`:

```
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
```

Output:

```
                              Date  Score  Month
0 2019-03-20 22:55:52.981000+00:00     10      3
1 2019-03-07 13:16:52.174000+00:00      9      3
2 2019-06-17 10:32:09.749000+00:00      1      6
```

---

From the documentation of [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) you can see a parameter:

> utc : boolean, default None
>
> Return UTC DatetimeIndex if True (converting any tz-aware datetime.datetime objects as well).

Comment: That fixed it. I needed to convert to datetime. Thank you!